# Split in two parts the content of string variable in Javascript and print it in two different divs

Tags: javascript

What I would like to do is to split the content of one variable in two parts and crate other two variables that I will be printing separately in two divs.

Here my code:

```
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body;
      var body = Math.ceil(str.length / 2);
      var s1 = str.slice(0, body);
      var s2 = str.slice(body);    
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = s1;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = s2;
    });
}
req1();
```

So what I'd like to do is to split the content of the "body" variable and print the first part in #newsContent and the second one in #newsContent2

Comment: Well, for starters `str` is undefined

Comment: And `body` is defined two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually your code is correct but the problem are your definitions, `body`, `str` everything is messed up.

here you have everything working.

```js
var title = "this is the title";
var phrase = "content1 content2"
var mid = Math.ceil(phrase.length / 2);
var s1 = phrase.slice(0, mid);
var s2 = phrase.slice(mid);

function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body;
      
      var length = Math.ceil(body.length / 2);
      var s1 = body.slice(0, length);
      var s2 = body.slice(length);
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = s1;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = s2;
    });
}
req1();
```

```html
<div id="newsTitle"></div>
<br>
<div id="newsContent"></div>
<br>
<div id="newsContent2"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I made a bit of confusion. Any idea why this doesn't work on Android browser?